# Activate ".bind" functions with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

**Goal:** Create a bookmarklet to quickly apply settings via dropdown menus on a particular website, [batchgeo.com](http://batchgeo.com).

**Issue:** Certain functions are triggered by the dropdown menus and I cannot figure out how to activate them via my bookmarklet.

**Current bookmarklet:**

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.getElementById('validate_button').click();
    document.getElementById('group_sel').value = 'City';
    document.getElementById('advanced_button').click();
    document.getElementById('labeltype_sel').value = 'none';
    document.getElementById('geocode_button').click();
})();
```

**Website Source:**

```
$("#group_sel").bind("change",function({
    per.group_col=rS(this);
    updatePreview(0);
    updateStylingOptions();
    updateColorOptions()
});
```

**Specific hangup:** The 'group_sel' menu has a ".bind" function that seems to be activated when on "change". While I can change the value of the menu, I cannot figure how how to impersonate this "change" to call the additional necessary functions.

Any assistance would be appreciated,
Thanks,
Mitch

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/change/

This call did the trick:

```
$('#group_sel').change();
```

Full, working bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.getElementById('validate_button').click();
    document.getElementById('group_sel').value = 'City';
    $('#group_sel').change();
    document.getElementById('advanced_button').click();
    document.getElementById('labeltype_sel').value = 'none';
    $('#labeltype_sel').change();
    document.getElementById('geocode_button').click();
})();
```